# What are the names of the characters used in beamer's itemize themes?

Tags: beamer

I know that I can modify an `itemize` environment via `\setbeamertemplate` and either `circle` `square`, `triangle`, `ball`.

What's the best way to mix different symbols within the same level of hierarchy?

Which are the correct commands to put into the optional arguments below to access the item shapes of `beamer`?

```
% this does not work as the optional arguments are not the right commands
\begin{itemize}
\item[\circle]  first bullet point
\item[\triangle] second bullet point
\item[\square] third bullet point
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the predefined beamer item shapes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\itemshape[1]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[#1]%
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[\itemshape{circle}]  first item
    \item[\itemshape{triangle}] second item
    \item[\itemshape{square}] third item
    \item[\itemshape{ball}] fourth item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mysquare}{\rule[0.0mm]{2.2mm}{2.2mm}~}
\newcommand{\mycirc}{\textbullet~}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}[0.1]
        \item[\mysquare] a
        \item[\mycirc] b
        \item[3) ] c
        \item[4) ] d
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]